# Loop exit while calling the sftp script inside the loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have written a shell script with name process.sh which calls the sftp script del.sh inside the loop. But once the sftp script(del.sh) is called, it is not coming back to process.sh

Process.sh

---

```
#!/bin/bash
for i  in $(ls *.csv)
do
 fbname=$(basename "$i" .csv)
echo "$fbname"
if [ -f $fbname.done ]
then
gzip $fbname.csv
exec /home/amithsa/del.sh $fbname.csv 
else
echo "File Not Found"
fi
done;
```

del.sh

---

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
spawn sftp xyz@10.10.10.10 22
expect "password:" 
send "xxxxxxxxx\n" 
expect "sftp>"
send "cd sftp\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "rm $arg1\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "rm *.html\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `exec` if you want the script to continue. `exec` will completely replace the current process with the command you give it. It never returns<sup>1</sup>.

Just call your script like you call `gzip` and `echo` and the other commands, i.e. directly.

```
gzip $fbname.csv
/home/amithsa/del.sh $fbname.csv
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Unless the command cannot be executed and, and you have the `execfail` option enabled. Or you're running an interactive shell.</sub>